# CSS sprites as background

Tags: css, background, icons, sprite

Is it possible to position a sprite icon as a background of an element?
I have a file, "icons.png" which contains several icons. I want to select one of those as a background of an element.
Usually I would use 
`.sprite {
    background: url('imgs/icons.png') no-repeat 0 -21px;
    width: 17px;
    height: 10px;
}` and use this class for a button, etc...

The problem is I have a text input and I want to modify it's placeholder
.First I did this, which works perfectly if the file I use is the icon itself

```
:-webkit-input-placeholder{ background: url('singleIcon.jpg') center right no-repeat; }
```

But now I want to use a file which contains more icons.
Is it possible to use something like this ?

```
:-webkit-input-placeholder{ background: url('imgs/icons.jpg') center right no-repeat; }
```

The problem in the last line of code is that it will select all my image (which of course contains **all my icons** I want to use on the website), I want to select only a part of that image  ( the icon I want to use )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the sprites are used only as background (or you've to set up some kind of complicated cropping).

What you have to do is to set the size of the element to the same sprite's part that you have to show, and the position of the background equal to the x and y coordinates of the icon in the sprite, starting from the top left.

---

An example taken from [this nice article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/):

[image: sprite example 1]

"Item 2" is 116x48, begins at 12px (x coord) and 70px (y coord).

So your element's CSS should be:

```
.element {
    width:116px;
    height:48px;
    background:url(sprites.png) -12px -70px no-repeat;
}
```

But, what if your element is taller/wider than the above dimensions? Then, you've to isolate that icon with enough transparent/white space so that the other icons won't show up.

[image: sprite example 2]

If you look up at [Facebook sprites](http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/facebook-sprite.png), you'll notice that some of them are very long, some others groupped, some others isolated. You've to adapt the sprite for each situation.

---

**Edit**: ok, i got your actual needing.

It's not easy with `input`s because you can't use pseudo-elements on it. Here comes a workaround.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/5kcnw/)**

First of all, wrap the input inside a div:

```
<div class="inputWrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text">
</div>
```

Then add some CSS:

```
div.inputWrapper {
    position:relative; /* that's important */
    float:left; /* or display:inline-block; */
}
div.inputWrapper:after {
    background:#000 url(sprites.png) 0 -2px no-repeat; /* adjust background position */
    content:" "; /* whitespace needed for the pseudo-element to be displayed */
    position:absolute;
    top:1px; right:2px; /* some room for the borders */
    width:16px; /* icon width */
    height:18px; /* icon height */
}​
div.inputWrapper input {
    padding-right:16px; /* so the text won't go behind the icon */
}
```

I know it's complicated, but the alternative is to create another http-request ... the choice is yours.

Comment: I want to position that icon at the right of my text input's placeholder, I don't want to modify my input's width

Comment: Also could you send me a link on " the alternative is to create another http-request ..." I'm new in this domain, and I'm intrested to know what that means :) thanks

Comment: @Vodaldrien you can read about it on this nice [Yahoo developers article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and also on [webpronews](http://www.webpronews.com/want-a-faster-website-reduce-requests-2-2012-03) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick n dirty sample. Basically, just set the background-position attribute of the element's CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var curFrame = 0;
var numFrames = 10;
var animTimer;

function advanceFrame()
{
    var hero;
    curFrame++;
    if (curFrame >= numFrames)
        curFrame = 0;

    hero = document.getElementById("hero");

    var posX = curFrame * -64;
    curPos = posX+"px 0";

    hero.style.backgroundPosition = curPos; //offsets[curFrame];
}

function myInit()
{
    animTimer = setInterval(advanceFrame, 200, false);
}
</script>
<style>
#hero
{   /* image is 638x64 pixels - it has 10 sprites in it, horizontally offset */
    background-image: url(http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-53-00-metablogapi/5545.image_5F00_13D4E783.png);
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='myInit();'>
    <div id='hero'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Vodaldrien - no worries mate. From one cioban to another. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but some things to note:

1. The placeholder pseudo-class works inconsistently across browsers, e.g. Firefox on the entire input element, Chrome only on line-height.
2. The placeholder pseudo-class by default adds a opacity layer on top of the original input box.
3. Background-images on the placeholder pseudo-class need to be "repeated" if the cropped icon is not the first icon on the sprite image.
4. The default box-sizing for form elements may be different for the rest of the elements, so borders/paddings may change the calculation of the size of your background-image.

I think it's best to keep your sprite a long vertical list of icons, make your placeholder style opaque, use the border-box box model. Also, the icon height dimension should be exactly the height of the available background space. It is also a good idea to keep the `background-*` properties separate so what you are doing with the sprites becomes clearer and easier to read.

Assuming you have a list of 4 50x50 icons - i.e. a 50x200 image, you can do the following:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;                 /* keep box-sizing consistent */
    width: 200px;
    height: 52px;                           /* compensate 2px for border */
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('icons.png');
    background-size: 50px 200px;
    background-position: right 20px top 0;  /* assuming you want the icon to "float" right */
    background-repeat: repeat-y;          
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url('icons.png');
    background-size: 50px 200px;
    background-position: right 20px top 50px; /* use second icon in the sprite */
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    opacity: 1;                               /* don't show the underlying input style */
}
```

Also remember to apply the styles to `::-moz-placeholder` and `:-ms-input-placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious, but have you tried:

```
:-webkit-input-placeholder{ background: url('imgs/icons.jpg')  no-repeat 0 -21px; width: 17px; height: 10px;
```

}

Comment: that won't work because my file contains more icons, and even if I position it where I want, other icons from that file will also appear on my background

Comment: ok well why dont you just insert the image as an `<img>` instead of using css to do it... that way you can define the exact size and position of it using css